# Coverting PPTx to HTML in java (with or without using Apache POI)

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to render office files in the html page but without uploading them online. I want to show them in the HTML page from my local host only. After failing on that I decided to convert office files into HTML and display them in separate iframe.
 For ppt,docx and doc i have used [this](https://code.google.com/p/office-to-html/source/browse/trunk/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/converter/DocxConverter.java?r=6) which uses Apache POI but i was not able to find anything that can do it for pptx files. Is there any simple way to do it?